# How do I execute a python file or function in that file on my website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, webserver

So I have a website and when I click a button I am running a javascript file to get some variables. After getting those variables I want to run some python with the variables the javascript collected. Then the python collects other data and stores it in a json file. After that the javascript loads the website page with the variables of the json file.

so in steps it is like this:

1. A button in the html is clicked
2. A javascript file gets some variables from the document (and passes them on to the python file OR stores them in a text file so the python file can read the text?)
3. A python file/function runs and collects some data that it stores in a json file
4. The javascript file generates html with the data in the json file

My problem is executing the python file from step 3. I am assuming it will need to be executed via a server, but I have no experience with a webserver. I don't know how to make it run the python script if that is even the solution.
Maybe it could it be ran via the javascript file?

I couldn't find any solutions (that I could understand) online, so I am asking here.

I would really appreciate the help! Let me know if you want some other details.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to run some python programs, I would like to recommend Flask to you.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/

With Flask you can easily start a webserver.

First of all you should install packages following the guides.

Then create a folder like:

- root

  - templates

    - html
    - css
    - js

Put your app.py in the root directory.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from api import api

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='templates')
app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("html/index.html")
```

Create API for the webserver.

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify, abort

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@api.route('/your-api', methods=['POST'])
def handle_your_api():
    // do sth
```

In this way you can call your python scripts in the program.

For the frontend, you should call those APIs to transmit data.

```
function call_your_api(data) {
  $.ajax({
    url: BASE_URL + "/your-api",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: // do sth
    error: // do sth
  });
}
```

This is just a simple example, you can find more details in the Flask homepage. I assume that you are experienced in python, so I guess you could master Flask quickly.